# Is there a way to persist an ELB stickiness session even if the instance its connected to fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, session, session-cookies, amazon-elb

Just curious if this is possible or how you would accomplish this.

Regardless if I use duration based stickiness or application based, when the instance a user is connected to fails their session gets reset because they have to connect to a new server.

Is there a way to not have this happen? To be able to have that session persist even if the instance they are connected to dies? Im also using SSL with a cert if that changes things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to accomplish that is persisting your session state in some **Storage service**, could be a database table, s3, Caching service, NoSQL table, Etc.

## These are some approaches

**Session state Inside Your Database**

> Saving session state inside the database is common in lightweight web frameworks like Django. That way you can add as many front servers as you like without having to worry about session replication and other difficult stuff. You don’t tie yourself to a certain web server and you get persistence and all other features databases provide for free. As far as I can tell, this works rather nicely for small to medium size websites.
>
> **The problem is the usual:** The database server may become your bottleneck. In that case your best bet may be to take a suitcase full of money to Oracle or IBM and buy yourself a database cluster.
>   **Reference:** [Saving Session Data in Web Applications](https://blog.mafr.de/2009/01/04/session-data-in-webapps/)

**Session state inside a Caching service**

> Amazon ElastiCache offers fully managed Redis and Memcached. Seamlessly deploy, operate, and scale popular open source compatible in-memory data stores. Build data-intensive apps or improve the performance of your existing apps by retrieving data from high throughput and low latency in-memory data stores.

**DynamoDB**

> Amazon DynamoDB is a fast and flexible NoSQL database service for all applications that need consistent, single-digit millisecond latency at any scale. It is a fully managed cloud database and supports both document and key-value store models. Its flexible data model, reliable performance, and automatic scaling of throughput capacity.

Regardless the approach you use, a middleware must be deployed along with your app to manage the stored session state.

**Middleware:** Could be either a thrid-party solution or your own solution.

## Resources

- [AWS Session Management](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/caching/session-management/)
- [Amazon ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/?nc1=h_ls)
- [Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)
- [Middleware for session management (Google results)](https://www.google.es/search?q=middleware%20for%20session%20mangagemnet&rlz=1C1GGRV_enES767ES770&oq=middleware%20for%20session%20mangagemnet&aqs=chrome..69i57.6271j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=strict)

Comment: Is this for SSL too? Doesn't that complicate things if ELB is setup with a cert and its an SSL connection being made to the server?

Comment: @red888 it doesn’t matter whether the ELB is using SSL certificate or not.